# Add a persistent message to iPhone main lock screen

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, screen-lock

I am looking for ways to have a permanent custom message/note on the primary lock screen on iOS 10+

Have tried [Lock Screen Note](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lock-screen-note/id930049673?mt=8) which does it via push notification, but problem is that as soon as I unlock the screen, the notification disappears and I have to re-activate the message in order to have it again.

Any other suggestions? I've seen it work with Norwegian app, that you have a constant message on the screen within a time span before your flight, and I would like to do the same for custom notes.

**Note** I cannot jailbreak my device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that the easiest way is to actually use the native Reminders.

- Write a reminder
- Set it to notify you 5 minutes from when you create it
- Enjoy a permanent message on the lock screen until you mark it done

Create as many reminders/notes/messages as you want.

[image]

Comment: Is there any other alternative to do this, like the Lock Screen Message feature in Android?

Answer (score 2):

If you want it permanent and not just a notification, you could use Photoshop (or similar program) or the built in iPhone photo editor to create a custom lock-screen background that includes the note. Depending on your frequency of changing the note and preference for it looking good anything from a imitation notification to a hand scribbled note could be achieved.

Answer (score 2):

You could try Apple Configurator, available for free on the Mac App Store. Once you’ve downloaded the app, you can set up a configuration that includes a persistent message. Be warned that this forces you to wipe your device, and that restoring from a backup will (as one may expect) wipe the configuration. It installs on the device as a profile.